# INSERT deleted values into a table before DELETE with a DELETE TRIGGER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-delete

For some reason I can't find the exact answer that I need. I searched for at last 20 minutes in here.

I know it's simple. VERY simple. But I can't fire the trigger for some reason..

I have a table with two columns

**dbo.HashTags**

```
|__Id_|_name_|
|  1  | Love |
```

I want to insert the deleted values into another table called `dbo.HashTagsArchive` on a `DELETE` query.

Example:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[HashTags] WHERE Id=1
```

After this example I should have the deleted row in `dbo.HashTagsArchive` and the row with `Id=1` should be deleted in `dbo.HashTags`

I tried this TRIGGER:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[HashTags_BeforeDelete]
    ON [dbo].[HashTags]
    FOR DELETE
AS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO HashTagsArchive
   ( Id,
     HashTagId,
     delete_date)
   SELECT d.Id, m.HashTagId,GETUTCDATE() FROM deleted d 
   JOIN dbo.HashTags m ON m.Id=d.Id
    DELETE FROM dbo.HashTags
    WHERE ID IN(SELECT deleted.Id FROM deleted)
  END
GO
```

It's getting `Deleted` but no `Inserted` row in the `HashTagsArchive`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is: this trigger fires **AFTER** the delete **has already happened**. So there is no more row in `HashTags` which you could join on!

You need to use this trigger instead:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[HashTags_BeforeDelete]
    ON [dbo].[HashTags]
    FOR DELETE
AS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO HashTagsArchive(Id, HashTagId, delete_date)
       SELECT 
           d.Id, d.HashTagId, GETUTCDATE() 
       FROM deleted d 
  END
GO
```

The `Deleted` pseudo table contains the **whole row(s)** that were deleted - no need to join on anything...

Also: this trigger fires after the delete has happened - so you don't need to do anything yourself, inside the trigger - just insert those bits of information into your archive table - that's all. Everything else is handled by SQL Server for you.