# Delete trigger to insert entry into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Created a `Customers_Audit` table in my `DEV_SQL` database with the columns:

```
[AuditID] int IDENTITY
[CustomerID] nchar(5)
[UserName] nvarchar(50)
[DeleteDate] smalldatetime
```

I am trying to write a delete trigger to insert an entry to the `Customers_Audit` table every time a row is deleted from the `Customers` table, need some help oh wise ones!

Comment: You can literally copy/paste the name of your post into Google and the answer is in the first 3 results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT deleted values into a table before DELETE with a DELETE TRIGGER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018982/insert-deleted-values-into-a-table-before-delete-with-a-delete-trigger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this - just insert the rows into `Customers_Audit` in your `AFTER DELETE` trigger and set the fixed values as needed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterDelete 
ON dbo.Customer
AFTER DELETE
AS 
    -- insert into the audit table - explicitly specifying the column names to use
    INSERT INTO dbo.Customers_Audit(CustomerId, UserName, DeleteDate)
        -- make sure to respect the fact that the "Deleted" table might
        -- contain *multiple* rows if your DELETE statement deleted 
        -- more than a single row - use proper set-based code!
        SELECT
            d.CustomerId, d.UserName, SYSDATETIME()
        FROM 
            Deleted d
```