# How to further process an item that is deleted in SQL

Tags: sql

myTable has columns `Id, Name, Type, MediaName, Folder`

blacklistTable has columns `Id, Media`

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE Name = "Missing" AND Type = "Movie"
```

Basically, I want to delete all items matching the `WHERE` statement from myTable, and for each item deleted, I want to add a column to blacklist table that has the deleted items `Id` and `MediaName`.    Is there some neat way to do this?

Comment: If you using SQL Server, check out Magic Tables ... no joke ... just google SQL Server Magic Tables

Comment: Why you want to add columns to a table according to deleted rows in another table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT deleted values into a table before DELETE with a DELETE TRIGGER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018982/insert-deleted-values-into-a-table-before-delete-with-a-delete-trigger)

Comment: careful when using @Veljko89's suggestion, when creating a trigger to accomplish the functionality you've described, you won't want the trigger to process for the deletes initiated from within the trigger.

Comment: @TimSchmelter sounds like auditing. Possibly an XY problem here. Maybe OP needs to look at soft deletes or another approach.

Comment: You want to add a *column* or rather a  *row* to your blacklist table?

Answer (score 1):

You could either just do a SELECT INTO before deleting your data.

Or you can use the [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) along with the INTO clause, like

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
OUTPUT DELETED.Id, DELETED.MediaName INTO Blacklist
WHERE Name = "Missing" AND Type = "Movie"
```